# PySpark 2.4 is not starting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been using PySpark 2.4 for some time. Spark was installed in my system at `/usr/local/spark`. Suddenly I see the error when I type `pyspark` in command line.

```
Failed to find Spark jars directory (/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars).
You need to build Spark with the target "package" before running this program.
```

System OS  = CentOS 7
I have Python 2.7 and Python3.6 installed. However, when I installed spark, then I set Python 3.6 as default.

There are couple of cronjobs that run every day (and have been running for quite sometimes) where `pyspark` is used. I am afraid such error like above may hinder to run those crons. 
Please throw some lights on this.

Comment: Even with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes it is just giving that error.